# How do you get multiple pieces of information out of a collection on a server?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

Here is a bit of the code I have

```
server.get("/get", getCallback);

function getCallback(req,res) {
    collection.find({}).next(findCallback);
    function findCallback(err,foundRecord) {
        if (err == null) {
            console.log('FOUND: ' + foundRecord);
            return res.status(200).send(foundRecord);
        }
        else
            throw err;
    }

}
```

It give's me back `{"readyState":1}` in the console.

No matter what I try it's giving me different types of errors. 
I have no problem-saving data to the collection but as soon
as I go to take it out nothing works.

Comment: probably you can try async/await(with driver v3) and refer to [find documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#find). Also please mention the mongodb driver api version you're using, because, v2 and v3 vary a lot.

Comment: use `Promise` rather than `callback`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `express` the `get` route takes the form:

```
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('your response document...')
})
```

You want to display a set of MongoDB collection documents in the browser at (the express server is listening on port 3000): `http://localhost:3000/get`

```
// Server
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const port = 3000;

server.listen(port, () => console.log('App listening on port ' + port));

// MongoDB client
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true } );

// Your get request
server.get('/get', function (req, res) {
    client.connect(function(err) {
        assert.equal(null, err)
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB server on port 27017')
        const db = client.db('test')
        const collection = db.collection('collectionName')
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            assert.equal(err, null)
            console.log('Found the following documents:')
            console.log(docs)
            res.send(docs)
            client.close()
        } )
    } )               
} );
```