# Trying to store mongo data in a variable and use it with hbs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I am trying to store MongoDB data in a variable and use it for display in HTML using hbs. The error I am getting is *TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined*. Here is the code I wrote:

```
evar express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoDB = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var hbs = require('hbs');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));

app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded());

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
var db;

mongoDB.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, function(error, client){
    if(error)
        throw error;
    db = client.db('attainu');
});

app.post('/addstudent/add', function(req, res){
    db.collection('students').insertOne(req.body, function(error, result){
        if(error)
            throw error;
        res.json(result);
        console.log("New student Successfully Added!");

    })
})

var students = db.collection('students').find({}).toArray();

app.get('/allstudents', function(req, res){
    res.render('students.hbs', {
        student: students
    });
})

app.listen(3000);
```

in the HTML file:

```
<body>
{{#each student}}
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">this.name</h5>
        <p class="card-text">this.email + this.age</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">this.number</a>
    </div>
</div>  
{{/each}} 
</body>
```

I think this is because JS is asynchronous language. It would be helpful if anyone could help me make this an asynchronous code.

Comment: See if this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114062/how-do-you-get-multiple-pieces-of-information-out-of-a-collection-on-a-server/61116648#61116648

Answer (score 0):

try

```
app.get('/allstudents', function(req, res){
    db.collection('students').find({},(err,students)=>{
        res.render('students.hbs', {
            student: students
        });
    });  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  app.get("/allstudents", async (req, res)=>{
      await db.collection("students").find({}, (error, students)=> {
      if(error) console.log(error);
      res.render("students.hbs", {
         student: students
      })
    })
  })
```

Use async to wait for your database operation to finish before continuing